# How to use Meta Viewport in XML?

Tags: css, xml, xslt, polyglot-markup

I am trying to create a responsive design layout using XML that relies on setting the `initial-scale` of the user agent. In HTML I would use some variation of the `<meta viewport>` tag such as this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1">
```

however the lack of a closing tag is a problem for XML.

Is there a way for me to do this in valid XML that would also work in browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506028/do-you-need-to-close-meta-and-link-tags-in-html) (which is specifically about closing the `<meta>` tag) I think the simplest thing to do here would be to just close the meta element with `/>` as browsers will not complain.

Answer (score 0):

Use the XHTML namespace:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Insert your content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

OR:

```
<html:meta xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" name="viewport" content="width=320, initial-scale=1"/>
```

**References**

- [Polyglot Markup: A Robust Profile of the HTML5 Vocabulary](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-polyglot/html-polyglot.html)
- [Sample Page using Polyglot Markup](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-polyglot/SamplePage.html)

Comment: For polyglot markup I still add an extra space before the `/>` self closing tags. makes no difference to xml parsers, and really ancient html parsers might get a tad bit happier.