# SVG Marker gets rendered differently on different screens

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

**Update**:

I figured out the screen issue. device pixel ratio is the culprit. On devices with lower window.devicePixelRatio the icon gets displayed smaller, a solution is to make the size of the icon conditional on window.devicePixelRatio, i.e. :

```
scaledSize: highDevicePixelRatio ? new google.maps.Size(40, 60) : new google.maps.Size(60, 90)
```

resolution might also play a role, but I couldn't test that as of now.

The issue with Internet Explorer 11 still exists though.

** **End Update** **

So this is really absurd and I am somewhat still baffled. I noticed this extremely inconsistent behavior of my custom markers. Drove me crazy, because I couldn't figure out why they would be behaving differently. I just now realized it depends on the screen I am displaying the map/marker on. I am using https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps.

I am using a MacBookPro 2015 and a LG 34UC98-W hooked up via HDMI cable.

But not only the screen, also the used browser gives different results. It works somewhat fine on chrome (differences in screens), the marker don't show up at all in IE 11 (haven't tested FireFox).

Now this is how I currently instantiate my marker:

```
const marker = {
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.state.center.lat,this.state.center.lng),
                    icon: {
                            url: icon_url(this.props.markerIcon,'purple'),
                            anchor: new google.maps.Point(13,42),
                            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(40, 60)    
                          },
                    draggable: false,
                }
```

**On my MacBook I get the following result:**
[image]
**On my LG I get the following result:**
[image]

This is driving me NUTS, is there a way to achieve consistent behavior across screens/browsers? What is the reason for this???

**Following the SVG Code:**

I tried with and without the explicit width and height attributes in the first svg tag. Does not make a difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-291 377 28 40" width="28px" height="40px" style="enable-background:new -291 377 28 40;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="pin" style="fill:#7261C3;stroke:#4B4080;stroke-width:0.6909;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="
    M-277,416.286c9.188-11.902,13-17.688,13-25.75c0-7.188-5.062-12.823-13-12.823s-13,5.635-13,12.823
    C-290,398.599-286.188,404.384-277,416.286z"/>
<g id="subject">
    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M-285.998,394.741c0.367,0.197,0.788-0.671,0.966-1.095c0.067-0.16,0.137-0.325,0.206-0.484
        c0.354-0.812,0.713-1.485,1.1-2.059c0.451-0.67,0.933-1.2,1.473-1.618c0.477-0.37,1.017-0.658,1.603-0.857
        c0.28-0.095,0.564-0.167,0.851-0.217c-0.172,0.361-0.319,0.733-0.437,1.11c-0.097,0.31-0.175,0.624-0.233,0.939
        c0.208,0.046,0.407,0.131,0.582,0.253c0.072,0.062,0.144,0.125,0.216,0.187c0.122-0.854,0.404-1.684,0.812-2.444
        c0.15-0.279,0.316-0.548,0.499-0.807c0.022-0.031,0.025-0.072,0.009-0.106c-0.016-0.034-0.05-0.057-0.088-0.06
        c-0.137-0.009-0.275-0.014-0.413-0.014c-1.407,0-2.814,0.473-3.928,1.336c-1.309,1.013-2.173,2.495-2.834,4.012
        C-285.864,393.397-286.442,394.479-285.998,394.741z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M-267.856,399.462l-0.017-0.056c-0.031-0.104-0.104-0.191-0.2-0.24
        c-0.097-0.049-0.209-0.057-0.312-0.021c-0.958,0.332-1.973,0.5-2.987,0.5c-0.685,0-1.37-0.077-2.037-0.233
        c0.14,0.316,0.274,0.635,0.4,0.956c0.536,0.09,1.083,0.135,1.637,0.135c0.848,0,1.693-0.107,2.511-0.319
        c0.254-0.066,0.504-0.141,0.75-0.226C-267.906,399.889-267.794,399.669-267.856,399.462z"/>
    <path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M-275.021,394.647c0.312-0.814,0.542-1.659,0.684-2.518c0.022-0.135,0.059-0.271,0.107-0.399
        c0.159-0.423,0.284-0.862,0.373-1.304c0.083-0.414,0.134-0.834,0.154-1.256c0.544,0.229,1.111,0.434,1.697,0.611
        c0.83,0.252,1.685,0.446,2.542,0.577c0.025,0.004,0.05,0.006,0.075,0.006c0.238,0,0.447-0.174,0.485-0.417
        c0.041-0.268-0.143-0.518-0.411-0.559c-0.811-0.124-1.621-0.308-2.406-0.546c-0.777-0.235-1.521-0.522-2.212-0.851
        c-0.374-0.178-0.752-0.378-1.117-0.571c-0.055-0.029-0.109-0.058-0.164-0.087l-0.138-0.073c-0.554-0.292-1.078-0.568-1.572-0.901
        c-0.407-0.273-0.791-0.586-1.142-0.927c-0.194-0.189-0.505-0.185-0.694,0.01c-0.189,0.194-0.185,0.505,0.01,0.694
        c0.393,0.383,0.824,0.732,1.279,1.038c0.459,0.309,0.942,0.573,1.417,0.825c-0.039,0.306-0.084,0.612-0.136,0.914
        c-0.088,0.518-0.196,1.038-0.321,1.55c-0.267,0.019-0.533,0.046-0.797,0.08c-0.179,0.023-0.388,0.053-0.598,0.122
        c-0.275,0.091-0.502,0.232-0.676,0.419c-0.225,0.243-0.328,0.533-0.404,0.745c-0.028,0.077-0.055,0.154-0.083,0.232
        c-0.334-0.326-0.679-0.641-1.034-0.945c-0.238-0.166-0.527-0.257-0.817-0.259c-0.29-0.002-0.58,0.086-0.82,0.249
        c-0.258,0.175-0.457,0.436-0.557,0.732c-0.1,0.295-0.101,0.623-0.003,0.919c0.955,2.143,2.443,4.046,4.293,5.489
        c1.172,0.914,2.487,1.645,3.882,2.158c0.084,0.031,0.178,0.01,0.241-0.053c0.063-0.063,0.084-0.157,0.053-0.241
        c-0.441-1.188-0.985-2.337-1.624-3.431c-0.26,0.242-0.603,0.508-0.997,0.685c-0.001-0.001-0.001-0.001-0.001-0.001
        C-275.871,396.518-275.389,395.605-275.021,394.647z M-275.542,391.889c-0.128,0.791-0.338,1.569-0.625,2.318
        c-0.107,0.28-0.225,0.555-0.354,0.826c-0.389-0.546-0.803-1.073-1.24-1.581c-0.082,0.171-0.182,0.333-0.3,0.482
        c-0.162,0.207-0.356,0.389-0.572,0.538c0.003-0.007,0.006-0.015,0.008-0.022c0.263-0.732,0.53-1.476,0.792-2.21
        c0.044-0.124,0.095-0.265,0.148-0.323c0.03-0.032,0.088-0.064,0.16-0.088c0.107-0.035,0.236-0.053,0.369-0.07
        c0.342-0.044,0.689-0.074,1.035-0.092c0.129-0.006,0.259,0.014,0.379,0.062c0.046,0.018,0.091,0.035,0.136,0.052
        C-275.56,391.798-275.534,391.843-275.542,391.889z"/>
    <ellipse style="fill:#FFFFFF;" cx="-274.416" cy="385.286" rx="1.486" ry="1.739"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: It looks like an issue with the SVG itself. Possibly with the viewBox attribute. Can you post your SVG code?

Comment: It seems like on one the SVG is being cropped and on the other it is being scaled down.  Is it possible the graphic should be smaller?

Comment: provided the svg code, let me know if this helps. The graphic itself is 26px 
 x 40px according to inkscape.

Comment: I added a bounty to the question, maybe you guys wanna have another look.

Comment: Can you try adding `size: new google.maps.Size(28, 40)` to the options as well as scaledSize and let me know if you still get the same result.

Comment: @PaulThomasGC would that fix the Internet Explorer Issue or the device size issue? As the device size I think I figured out (devicePixelRatio). Cheers

Comment: The size issue. I had only skim read and not noticed the IE11 issue. I think, actually, IE11 has a real problem with SVG markers in google maps, it's to do with canvas support (which is used to render the markers). You could also try setting `optimised: false` in the options which means it should render without canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue recently and had to change the meta tag in my html to work across devices. Seems like currently you don't have one so maybe try adding the following to your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```

If you're only modifying the XML then you may have to use /> to close the tag or use the xml namespace as referenced [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979092/how-to-use-meta-viewport-in-xml)