# Get the time duration of a film and add it to a Google spreadsheet through IMPORTXML

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to fetch, for personal use, from the IMDB mobile website the time duration of a film and add it to a Google Sheets. Lets take for example this URL [m.imdb](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2096673/), as you can see below the title, there is the film specs.
I've checked the HTML and what I'm looking for is:

```
    <time itemprop="duration" datetime="PT94M">
                94 min
    </time>
```

I've tried lots of XPath like:

```
=IMPORTXML(M8;"...")


 1. //*[@id="titleOverview"]/div[2]/div/p/time
 2. //*[@itemprop='duration']
 3. /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[2]/div/p/time
 4. //time[@itemprop='duration']
```

and many others of them, but seems like I'm doing something wrong, because every time the cell return `#N/A`.

I did the same thing with the rating, like this:

```
<span class="inline-block text-left vertically-middle">8,6<small class="text-muted">/10<br>109.569</small></span>

=IMPORTXML(M9;"//span [@class='inline-block text-left vertically-middle']")
```

and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the length by using this:

```
=regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTXML("http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2096673/","//p[1]")),"(\d+ min)")
```

or this if you use semicolon instead:

```
=regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTXML("http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2096673/";"//p[1]"));"(\d+ min)")
```

Comment: This answer is helpful because gives a solution but it doesn't explains why the xPath queries that the OP included in the question doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler alternative formula to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5617035/aurielle-perlmann) by [Aurielle Perlman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5617035/aurielle-perlmann)

Create a new sheet, then add the following:

Cell A1: `http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2096673/`
Cell A2: `//p`
Cell A3 formula: `=Index(importxml(A1,A2),1,3)`
Cell A3 display value/result: `95 min`

---

The problem with the referred source is that it doesn't follow the XHTML rules: the first p element includes a meta tag that is not closed. The following HTML was extracted using the Chrome developer console from http://m.imdb.com/title/tt2096673/

```
<p class="infobar ellipse">


        <meta itemprop="contentRating" content="PG">PG



                &nbsp;<span class="ghost">|</span>&nbsp;
            <time itemprop="duration" datetime="PT95M">
                95 min
</time>
                &nbsp;<span class="ghost">|</span>&nbsp;
<span class="itemprop" itemprop="genre">Animation</span>, <span class="itemprop" itemprop="genre">Adventure</span>, <span class="itemprop" itemprop="genre">Comedy</span>
    </p>
```

Note that the meta tag is not closed properly according to the XHTML rules. This is the reason that explains why the xPath queries included in the question doesn't work.

Further reading:

- [Do you need to close meta and link tags in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506028/do-you-need-to-close-meta-and-link-tags-in-html)

Answer (score -1):

I used this for imdb rating

```
=importXml(I2, "//div[@class='imdbRating'][1]" )
```

I2 is link to movie