# xslt to html: link and meta tag never closed

Tags: html, xslt, saxon

I am transforming XML to HTML with XSLT 2.0 and Saxon9he. The problem I am having is that the link and meta tags in the head are not closed in the output, causing an error when opening the files in Chrome.

In my stylesheet:

```
<xsl:result-document method="html" href="HTML/index.html" encoding="utf-8">
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;</xsl:text>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>cat</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
                </head>
                <body>
...
</xsl:result-document>
```

But in the output:

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
 <title>cat</title>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="styles.css">
```

Why aren't these tags closed?

Comment: In HTML empty elements like `link` or `meta` are marked up as `<meta  ...>` or `<link  >`, so that is the right syntax for HTML. Which error does Chrome give you, what are you doing with the HTML document created by XSLT?

Comment: Perhaps you are serving the files with an XML media type? You could always try `<xsl:output method='xhtml'/>`, which would probably solve the problem, but it would be nice to know why it's happening first.

Comment: Relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19506028/272735 that answers this question too. This is not a Saxon nor XSLT issue but related to the two different HTML5 serializations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by saying

```
<xsl:result-document method="html"
```

you are requesting for the result to be HTML, and not XML. if you want the output to be XML (or XHTML, as an XML-compliant variant of HTML), then you have to select output methods `xml` or `xhtml`. if you choose either of those, your output document will be well-formed XML.