# Meta Tag showing error

Tags: javascript, html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I have a page on which both of these tags are used . I was trying to remove w3c errors ,So I `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` closed this tag. Then this tag started coming in red color(only /> part is coming in red).Am I making any error ? also can someone clear me the meaning of both of the tags.

Comment: see this thread [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506028/do-you-need-to-close-meta-and-link-tags-in-html) it may help you

Answer (score 0):

`<meta charset="utf-8"/>` is not necessary to add at the end.

if you want to end the tag Specifically use below

```
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
```

Comment: ["Tag omission in text/html: no end tag"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element:concept-element-tag-omission)

Comment: I have tried this also.IT is giving same . My qauestion is can we use both these meta tags together on same page ?