# Need to convert the not closed meta element HTML to XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I have worked on changing the HTML to XML, I'm having the not closed Meta element in the HTML Input.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Sample</title>
   </head>
</html>
```

Not closed meta elements are not showing any validation error in the Input, but while doing conversion I'm getting the below error:

```
The element type "meta" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</meta>"
```

XSL I'm tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
    version="2.0">

      <xsl:template match="html">
       <document>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </document>
      </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="head">
    <head>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </head>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <title>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </title>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:param name="unparse" select="'file:///C:test.htm'"/>

  <xsl:template match="saxon:meta">
    <xsl:value-of select="saxon:parse-html($unparse)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tried the `saxon:parse-html` in the XSLT, But I can't able to convert. So I need to remove the not closed Meta element using XSLT. I'm using saxon-PE 9.9.1.5.

Comment: Not sure what element you're hoping to match with `match="saxon:meta"`. I think it's not matching anything and therefore parse-html() is never being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your code with a named template e.g. in XSLT

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse-html(unparsed-text($unparse))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and option `it:main` from the command line. That should show you the tree and its default serialization you get from the `parse-html` method.

I think it outputs elements in the XHTML namespace by default, not in no namespace as HTML 4 would. Thus if you want to transform elements returned from `parse-html` you will need to match on that namespace e.g. `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` on your `xsl:stylesheet` and then your template like the one mapping `html` to `document` should work if you use

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="saxon:parse-html(unparsed-text($unparse))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that 9.9 supports XSLT 3 so you could use the `name="xsl:initial-template"` instead of `name="main"` and save you having to spell out the initial template's name as option `-it` defaults to that template.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you not use:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

The Xslt processor throws an error because every element must have an open and close tag.

--
In XHTML, XML rules apply, so every element, without exception, must have both a start tag and an end tag, but the same tag may be used for both roles if the element content is empty, e.g.  as short for .

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19510239/3692798